# Error in setting up the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

What is wrong with my code? When Im setting up the connection between my sql and asp, it gives me this error : the sqlcommand cannot be found. Are you missing...."

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;

  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab( Brand,Model,Plate,Color,Service) Values (@brand,@model,@plate,@color,@year,@service)",conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", Label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", Label2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plate", Label3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", Label4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Label5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service", Label6.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I've already put Using system.data; and Using system.data.sql; but it still the same.
Error : 
1.The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a     using directive or an assembly reference?) 
2.The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3.The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context 
4.The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
5.The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Hope this help you in finding solution for my errors. Thanks

Comment: Have you used `sqlcommand` as in the same case shown in the msg somwhere ?

Comment: Don't forget your `using` blocks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things. You haven't closed your SQL command:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab")
```

And secondly, you don't have any qualifying data to insert in to your CarTab table? You need to specify the fields and values:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab(field1, field2) VALUES('val1', 12)")
```

There are a number of other ways to insert data - like the INSERT SELECT:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab(field1, field2) SELECT field1, field2 FROM Table2")
```

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records

Further to the comments, here is an example of how to fully use ADO in the way you have specified:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

            using (var con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")) {
                con.Open();
                using (var com = con.CreateCommand()) {
                    var var1 = "test";
                    var var2 = "test2";
                    com.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Table1(col1, col2) VALUES({0}, {1})", var1, var2);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
```

Please note that I haven't tested it, but it should give you a good starting block.

Comment: Yeah I know. But the point now is sqlconnection, command, something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: You need to be clearer on your question and post the full error and answer.

You also need to open your connection (conn.Open()) and associate it with your command (cmd.Connection = conn). I will amend my answer with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added reference to System.Data assembly?

Comment: How to add it? Can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have not closed the SqlCommand object and wrong Sql Insert statement.
It would be

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab(col1,col2,...) VALUES(val1,val2,..)");
```

2) You have not open the connection and not assign a connection to a command object like

```
 conn.Open();
 cmd.Connection = conn;
```

3) and after executing the query you have to close the connection

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close(); // close the connection.
```

Comment: I think the error he's getting is at compile time, so even though the conn.Open() parts are correct, it's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.Sql is for SqlServer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.aspx

> The System.Data.Sql namespace contains classes that support SQL
>   Server-specific functionality.

Use the ADO.NET driver found here:  http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

or use ODBC (not the preferred option).

Answer (score 0):

what kind of db program are you using? since like grayfox said here above you are in need of sql server, and try doing it this way, worked fo rme:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            string connectionStringName = this.DataWorkspace.dbsMSccData.Details.Name;

            connection.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;

            string procedure = entity.Procedure;
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //foreach (var item in entity.StoredProcedureParameters)
                //{
                //    command.Parameters.Add(
                //        new SqlParameter(item.ParameterName, item.ParameterValue));
                //}

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        this.Details.DiscardChanges();
```